# SharePoint 2013 Web Application Association for SSRS

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013, reporting-services-2012

We are running into an issue when we try and setup a new SSRS Application within Central Administration.
I am able to set the Name, App Pool, Configurable App Pool Account, Database Server, Database Authentication, but unable to set the Web Application Association.

The first time I setup the Application it allows me to select the Service Application Sites. When I return back to the Properties, Above the Web Application Association I get this message:

"There are no web applications available to associate with this sql server reporting services server application."

I am suck and cant seem to get this resolved. Has anyone came across this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

You have to approach this in a different way; instead of configuring the associated Web Applications within the Service App. Config, you change the Service Application Associations (Central Admin > Application management > Service Applications > Configure Service Application Associations)

Once there, click on the Application Proxy Group that you're using - in my case, this was 'default'.

That will then pop open a window - "Configure Service Application Associations". Simply untick your old SSRS Service Application and tick the new one.

While it doesn't solve your exact issue... A combination of this and another proxy group might do what you want.